# C# Insert Into Access database Not working and getting no exception or error

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert, oledb

I'm trying to insert data in a access database but not working! Getting no exception and no error! and ExecuteNonQuery() returning 1.

```
if (int.TryParse(ctl.Text, out value))
{
    conn.Open();
    repondants = value;
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Réponses]([NumReponse], [École], [Année], [Sexe], [Question_Texte], [Réponse_Num], [Répondants])Values('254','" + ecole + "','" + annee + "','" + sexe + "','" + question + "','" + reponse + "','" + repondants + "')");
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
else
{
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Erreur: Please insert only numbers!");
}
```

**EDIT**
I tried parameters and it's not working too!

```
if (int.TryParse(ctl.Text, out value))
{
    conn.Open();
    repondants = value;
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Réponses]([École], [Année], [Sexe], [Question_Texte], [Réponse_Num], [Répondants])Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ecole", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ecole;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@annee", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = annee;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sexe", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = sexe;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@question", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = question;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@reponse", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = reponse;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@repondants", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = repondants;

    count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
else
{
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Erreur: Please enter numbers only!");
}
```

Comment: If ExecuteNonQuery returns 1 then a row has been added. Where, is another matter. Check your connectionstring and be sure to look at the same database. Side note. Learn as soon as possible how to use parameterized queries. If one of your strings contains a single quote the code will crash. Not to mention Sql Injection

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I checked and I'm looking at the good database. And I justed tried with the basic insert query (I will use parameterized query as soon as it work)

Comment: I'd strongly consider using parameters from the start, since they also tend to be less error-prone. Making the switch might fix your bug, because I don't see an obvious one except you handling all variables as a string, and using parameters will fix that

Comment: I will try that!

Comment: Try putting spaces before and after the word "VALUES" in your SQL statement.

Comment: Not working too

Comment: Well, this baffles me. For debugging purposes, I'd try the same query on a new, blank database, with only this table added (preferably not copied but created from scratch) to make sure it's not corruption/data macros/VBA on startup interfering here, I'd triple-check the types in the database (you're still treating them all as text fields) and use `OleDbType.VarWChar` as all Access text fields are actually UTF-16.

Comment: I'll try that thanks

Comment: Are all the columns you inserting into of type text, or are some columns of number type? I would open up the access table in design mode, and double check the data types of the columns - they need to match correct data types.

Comment: Are you sure the `if` statement is `true`?